# Access object component in redux state reducers

Tags: reactjs, oop, redux, react-redux, state

I have just started to learn `redux` and I was wondering how to access object component in redux `reducers`. I want to access the `address` component inside the user but is unable to because it is the key. Is there a way to access it? Here is my code:

```
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  user: {},
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  case SET_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
   return {
    ...state,
    state.user.addresses: payload, //how to access the addresses property from here?
   }
};
```

Comment: What does exactly contains the `payload` variable?

Comment: It contains an address object @EmanueleScarabattoli

Comment: @Cococrunch check my answer, if I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operation "..." lets you assign a new value to the properties of an object.
if one of the properties is an object and you want to assign a new value to one of its properties, you need to spread it as well and so on.

For example:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  case SET_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
   return {
    ...state, 
    user: { 
      ...state.user, 
       addresses: payload
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it does not work as for the spread operator, it is said that `user` in `...user` is not identified but it works when I use `...state.user` instead

Answer (score 1):

You have a `user` property in your initial state but then you try to assign another property `state.user.buyer.addresses` which is wrong because what you actually want to do is update the `addresses` inside the `user` object.

Easy and quick way to deep clone your `user` object would be to stringify it and then parse it.

```
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.user));
```

then you could assign the new addresses

```
clone.buyer.addresses = payload.addresses
```

Finally update your state with the new `user` object

```
  case SET_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
   return {
    ...state,
     user: clone
   }
```

Comment: thank you this answer works too but its a bit long hahaha